# WinForms form partially loses focus after disabling all controls

Tags: winforms, focus

The focus rectangle and textbox caret are lost after disabling all controls, then enabling them again (vs2012 / .NET Framework v4.5).

To reproduce the issue, just create a WinForms application project, add a button and a textbox in the form, then use this code to disable and enable both controls in the button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    textBox1.Enabled = false;

    button1.Enabled = true;
    textBox1.Enabled = true;
}
```

You may cycle between the textbox and the button using Tab/Shift+Tab as expected, until you press the button.

After that, the focus is partially lost (its weird). You can still use Tab/Shift+Tab and arrows to nagivate between the controls, and press Enter to active the button, but you cannot type in the textbox, nor use the space key to press the button. The textbox caret and the button focus rectangle are not displayed anymore. Changing focus to another application then returning to this form will fix the focus issue.

This issue does not happen if you don't disabled at least one control that is able to receive focus. Also the focus behavior is restored by disabling and enabling again the form, like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        textBox1.Enabled = false;

        button1.Enabled = true;
        textBox1.Enabled = true;

        this.Enabled = false;
        this.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I was trying to disable all the controls of a more complex form at the start of a task, so the task would enable again all controls after finishing, to prevent user input during the processing, but without locking the UI thread. I thought it was related to the cross-thread invoke calls, but I found this issue happens even with all code running on UI thread.

Comment: This is entirely normal.

Comment: Never mind, I found just calling this.Focus() after enabling the controls fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This undesired behavior can be fixed by calling the form Focus() method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    textBox1.Enabled = false;

    button1.Enabled = true;
    textBox1.Enabled = true;

    this.Focus();
}
```

The ActiveControl is not changed after calling Focus(), so this works very well for me.